# How can you make it so that only a certain role can use a command on a discord bot?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, nextcord

It's so that if this person in the server has a certain role, eg. "giveaway person" they are alloud to make a giveaway, but not anyone else

I didnt really try much, since I only learned to use the Nextcord library and not Discord library

Answer (score 1):

Going through the nextcord documentation a bit I found this: [has_role(item)](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/latest/ext/application_checks/index.html#nextcord.ext.application_checks.has_role)

> A check() that is added that checks if the member invoking the command has the role specified via the name or ID specified.
>
> **If a string is specified, you must give the exact name of the role, including caps and spelling.** 
> **If an integer is specified, you must give the exact snowflake ID of the role.** 
> **If the message is invoked in a private message context then the check will return False.**
>
> Parameters: 
> item (Union[int, str]) – The name or ID of the role to check.

This is a small example that I found in the same documentation:

```py
@bot.slash_command()
@application_checks.has_role('Cool Role')
async def cool(interaction: Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message('You are cool indeed')
```

There is also a [has_any_role(*items)](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/latest/ext/application_checks/index.html#nextcord.ext.application_checks.has_any_role) method if you want to match multiple roles.

```py
@bot.slash_command()
@application_checks.has_any_role('Moderators', 492212595072434186)
async def cool(interaction: Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message('You are cool indeed')
```